# Asp.net menu's last submenu to show at right side

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu

I am using asp.net menu and is working properly except the last submenu's direction doesn't change from left to right and the content of the submenu is hiding after the edges of my screen.

My Master page code

```css
<style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%; /* Sets the body to fill the whole screen */
            width: 100%;
           overflow-x: hidden; 
        }

        #button1 :hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: White;
        }

        #button2 {
            color: white;
            background: red;
        }

        .shadBrd1 {
            background: url( '../Images/en-us/SiteShad1.gif' ) repeat-y right 50%;
        }

        .shadBrd2 {
            background: url( '../Images/en-us/SiteShad2.gif' ) repeat-y left 50%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .ftrArea {
            background: #c8c8c8 url( '../Images/ftrBg.gif' ) repeat-X right top;
            margin-top: 10px;
            height: 29px;
            width: 74%;
            text-align: center;
            bottom: 0px;
        }

        .mainTbl {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 955px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .bodyhd {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        #form1 {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #form2 {
            height: 229px;
            width: 974px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: ١٠px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            color: #595959;
            border: 0px;
        }

        .style8 {
        }

        .style9 {
            height: 132px;
        }

        .style10 {
            font-size: smaller;
            height: 75%;
            direction: rtl;
            bottom: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .style11 {
            height: 29px;
            text-align: center;
            bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            background: #c8c8c8 url('../Images/ftrBg.gif') repeat-X right top;
        }

        .style12 {
        }

        .style14 {
            color: #CC3300;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-family: Verdana;
        }

        .copyR {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: x-small;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        #Progress_bar {
            position: absolute;
            left: 40%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -30px; /* make this half your image/element height */
            margin-left: -30px; /* make this half your image/element width */
            color: #CC3300;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>


       


        <div style="height: 100%;">
            <table class="mainTbl" style="width: 1000px; text-align: right; height: 100%;" align="center"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="White" rowspan="8" valign="top" class="shadBrd2">
                        <img alt="" src="../Images/en-us/SiteShad2.gif" style="width: 20px; height: 26px" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left" class="style8" colspan="2"></td>
                    <td bgcolor="White" rowspan="8" valign="top" class="shadBrd1">
                        <img alt="" src="../Images/en-us/SiteShad1.gif" style="width: 20px; height: 26px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right" class="style12">
                      

                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        <strong><span class="style14"></span> &nbsp;
                            &nbsp;</strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style9" colspan="2">
                        <img alt="" src="../Images/header_img.jpg" style="width: 1000px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td id="div_Menu" bgcolor="#1C5E55" class="style8" colspan="2" style="height: 25px;">
                        <div style="background-position: center;">
                            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" CssClass="menu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="1" StaticSubMenuIndent="1px"
                                DataSourceID="MenuSource" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" Orientation="Horizontal"
                                runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False"
                                StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" IncludeStyleBlock="false" ItemWrap="True"
                                RenderingMode="List" StaticPopOutImageUrl="../Images/down.gif"
                                OnMenuItemDataBound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound"

                                >
                            </asp:Menu>
                            
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MenuSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="true" StartFromCurrentNode="false" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                       
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr class="bodyhd" valign="top">
                    <td class="style10" colspan="2">

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                        <div style="background-color: #1C5E55; font-size: large; color: White">
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="MainProgress" DisplayAfter="1" runat="server">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                    <div id="ProgressDiv">
                                        يرجى الانتظار للتحميل.... 
                                    </div>
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style11" colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCopyright" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblCopyrightResource1"
                            CssClass="copyR"> </asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

i have used   "overflow-x: hidden;" in html, body to hide the unnecessary white space with horizontal scrollbar at leftside. and before that the submenu was visible when i scroll to left but the space with scrollbar was never ending.it was going very long.

my image link is here 
http://i59.tinypic.com/2zqdiy1.jpg

i dont have reputation so it is not allowing me to post image here.

```html
My Menu Code is like this
 <tr>
                    <td id="div_Menu" bgcolor="#1C5E55" class="style8" colspan="2" style="height: 25px;">
                        <div style="background-position: center;">
                            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" CssClass="menu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="1" StaticSubMenuIndent="1px"
                                DataSourceID="MenuSource" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" Orientation="Horizontal"
                                runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False"
                                StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" IncludeStyleBlock="false" ItemWrap="True"
                                RenderingMode="List" StaticPopOutImageUrl="../Images/down.gif"
                                OnMenuItemDataBound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound"

                                >
                            </asp:Menu>
                            
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MenuSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="true" StartFromCurrentNode="false" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and the css

```css
div.menu {
    background-color: #1C5E55;
  
}


    /* To avoid flickering of asp.ne menu   A52A2A*/
    /* *************************/
    div.menu > ul > li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
    }

    div.menu ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    /* *************************/

    div.menu ul {
        background-color: #1C5E55;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-weight: 600;
        z-index: 999;
        
    }

        div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
            /*background-color: #5c5c5c;*/
            border-bottom: 1px #5c5c5c solid;
            color: white;
            display: block;
            line-height: 1.35em;
            padding: 4px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        div.menu ul.level1 {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

       

        div.menu ul li a:hover {
            /* background-color: #bfcbd6;     color: #465c71;*/
            background-color: #84BF99;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        div.menu ul li a:active {
            background-color: #465c71;
            color: #cfdbe6;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        div.menu ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 0 20px;
            margin: 0px 0;
            line-height: 35px;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-right: 1px solid Gray;
        }


ul > li:first-child a {
    border: none;
}

div.menu ul li a.level1 {
    border-bottom: none;
}

div.menu ul li a.level2 {
    border-bottom: none;
}

div.menu ul li a[title] {
    border-bottom: none;
}


/* to manipulate dropped menu*/
div.menu ul li  ul li a
{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Please help me. i am struck into it.

I have asked the same question here 
http://forums.asp.net/t/2037911.aspx?Asp+net+menu+submenu+problem but i didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys, i would have tried bit more before posting here.

i have solved by adding these lines to my navigation menu css

ul:first-child > li:last-child ul.level4
{
margin-right:-300px
}